# How to use ng-bind for my model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

From the documentation, its clear, with ng-bind we can update our HTML, How to use the same functionality for updating my model.

```
<input type="text" ng-bind="controller.model.property">
```

I don't want to use ng-model, Don't want to reflect changes in my input box when data is fetched from the backend.

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to reflect changes in your Input Box?

Comment: The "property" has some value in my model, I don't want the property value to be shown in my input box as would happen, if I use ng-model, I want it one-way. input => model.property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want two-way data binding, I assume that you will process all the data at once (perhaps on a button click). The way I would do it is by creating a temporary scope variable to assign using ng-model, and then assigning it to the original variable on button click.

```
//template
<input type="text" ng-model="temp.property">
<button ng-click="submit()">Save</button>

//controller
$scope.model = updateViaBackend();
$scope.temp = { property: "" };

$scope.submit = function(){
  $scope.model.property = $scope.temp.property;
}
```

Comment: Yes, its a nice work around, Even I was thinking on the same lines, just didn't want an extra variable to the scope. Thanks!

Comment: and I think you should use ng-model="temp.property" instead of ng-bind="temp.property"

Comment: You're right! I've changed it now. What you can do to keep your `$scope` a bit cleaner is by keeping the temporary variables in a container object. In my example I used `temp` but you could also call it `form` if you're creating a form, for example.